# Error Message on Ubuntu One Page

Tags: ubuntu-one

I get the following message when ubuntu one loads and cannot sync contacts.

```
Value could not be retrieved. Value could not be retrieved. (DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process /usr/lib/deskt
```

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

1)Try to run ubuntu one from terminal without using sudo

```
ubuntuone-control-panel-gtk
```

If it doesnt work:

Run in terminal:

```
echo -e "[logging]\nlevel = DEBUG" > ~/.config/ubuntuone/logging.conf; u1sdtool -q; u1sdtool -c
```

1. Copy files into your ~/Ubuntu One folder and let it run for awhile to collect information.
2. Open your home folder
3. Click the View->Show Hidden Files menu option
4. Open the .cache/ubuntuone/ folder
5. Right click on the log/ folder and select "Compress"
6. Click OK and you should have a file named "log.tar.gz" in the .cache/ubuntuone folder, move this file to your Desktop since it's in a hidden folder which can be hard to find in the next step
7. You can attach the log.tar.gz archive to an email to Ubuntu One Support.

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1799348